# first update query is execute but second update query not execute in ubuntu server. ubuntu is installed in oracle vmware

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use laravel task scheduler, here some code snap of my kernel.php file:

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\GetUserLogInfo@getUserInfo')
                ->everyMinute();
```

this function call `GetUserLogInfo` controller's `getUserInfo()` function using artisan schedule:run command. command runs but results are not coming as I required.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What query? What are the desired results? Does the issue resolve on a different server environment? (if not, issue is unrelated to Ubuntu)